# Вычитание значений между таблицами Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 идентичные по полям таблицы в одной БД.sirovyna и zayavki . Подскажите пожалуйста каким запросом можно отнять значения kol из одной таблицы от значения kol в другой таблице. Поля id и naim у них будут одинаковые.[Таблица sirovyna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZhU9.png)

[image: Таблица zayavki]

Answer (score 2):

Это в том случае если нужно получить разницу:

```
SELECT (s.kol - z.kol)
FROM sirovyna s
JOIN zayavki z ON s.id = z.id AND s.naim = z.naim;
```

Это в том случае если нужно изменить первую таблицу:

```
UPDATE sirovyna AS s
JOIN zayavki AS z ON s.id = z.id AND s.naim = z.naim
SET s.kol = (s.kol - z.kol);
```